# How do I add more column for my line charts?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, charts

Hope everyone is doing fine. I was able to get my combined bar-line chart to finally display itself. However, running it gives me a problem: All the line charts follow the same column data as the bar chart when I wanted to have the line charts within the bar chart choose between each column instead, as seen here:

[As seen here, the line chats(by the names of Bpples, Cpples and Dpples) are picking the same colums for data as (Apples) instead of picking different colums for their data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZmew.png)

Here's my GS code:

```
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Chart');
    
}
function getCases(){
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const casesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ChartDATA0AAA');
const getLastrow=casesSheet.getLastRow();

return casesSheet.getRange(4,1,getLastrow-1,34).getValues();
}
```

I am wondering if something on my GS code as I know its missing but I don't know what's missing. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It appears you are drawing the chart in html.  It's not a chart in Google Sheet.  You should be able to manipulate the column data as you see fit.

Comment: Which parts you do not understand? Mostly for me I'm trying to have the html line charts pick up the other columns instead of the same column that the base bar chart is using.

Comment: How are you drawing the chart?